# How do I read a gzipped CSV file?

Tags: csv, go, gzip

I'm facing some issues in reading archived CSV files.

So I want to use the `csv` package and the `gzip` package for this, but I don't know how to combine them.

The `gzip.Reader(p []bytes)` and the `csv.Reader()` have different signatures.

This is my reader function:

```
func reader(filename string, c chan string) {
    fi, err := os.Open(filename)
    var r *bufio.Reader
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("%q",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fz, err := g.NewReader(fi)

    if err != nil {
        r = bufio.NewReader(fi)
    }else {
        r = bufio.NewReader(fz)
    }


    for {
        line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("done reading file")
            c <- "done"
            break
        }else{
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%q",strings.Fields(line))
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: First: Buffer before unzipping. Second: Whats wrong with plugging the `fz` into `csv.NewReader`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just Open the file for reading, then use that file handle with gzip and then use that file handle for the csv reader:

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("data.csv.gz")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    gr, err := gzip.NewReader(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer gr.Close()

    cr := csv.NewReader(gr)
    rec, err := cr.Read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, v := range rec {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

and this is my (uncompressed) `data.csv`:

```
"foo","bar","baz"
```

The output of my program is:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With a little tweaking, I've been able to do the same but using bzip2 instead of gzip — the concept is similar enough for me to figure it out1

Comment: How can I modify the code to have it read for just first `n` lines of a super large file?